# Is it possible to set a variable's value in an AJAX request?

Tags: javascript, ajax

If not, what would be a workaround?

Something like this:

Page 1:

```
<script>
  var test = '';

    *** AJAX Request to Page 2 ***

  document.write(test);
</script>
```

Page 2:

```
<script>test = "test Data";</script>
```

Comment: Consider returning JSON and setting the value from there.

Comment: Why not just load the script? You can use `document.write()`, and it'll write the `<script>` tag to the page so that it's loaded synchronously.

Comment: It's hard to tell what you're trying to do but you may be interested in http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP

Comment: @CrazyTrain because it is dynamic.

Comment: @reformed: *What* is dynamic?

Comment: @CrazyTrain the event selected by the user that will return page 2 data.

Comment: The code in your question keeps changing. Please describe exactly what you want. How is the user selecting this? The way your question is written, there's no event. It's just inline content loading.

Comment: If you are using html5, you can use localstorage to do that.

Comment: The data is pulled from a SQL table

Comment: What kind of ajax request do you want to perform and what is its response?

Comment: @CrazyTrain someone removed the PHP I originally had.

Comment: @k0pernikus page2 will retrieve data from a SQL table and assign it to the Javascript variable

Comment: @reformed That is a perfect use case to jsonfy the data and request that instead of a html page. If want to use your current html page, consider the use of data-attributes and read them in the callback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not set the variable value in the callback of the ajax request?
Something like this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "test.html",
    context: document.body
}).done(function(res) {
    test = res.value;
});
```

The script from page 2 can return an JSON Object like {value: 'test Data'}

Comment: Is it possible to do this without jQuery?

Comment: @reformed http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8567114/how-to-make-an-ajax-call-without-jquery

Answer (score 0):

You can set variables with the page you request, if this page runs some javaScript.  I assume your ajax request is calling page 2?

However, it would make more sense, I think, to set the variable in the callback of your ajax request.

Since you did not list any server side languages, I'm also assuming you are talking about changing client-side variables.